# Why isn't eq working with my string input?

Tags: perl

Just started to learn Perl and namely, learn program flow - main notable differences between evaluating strings and number and using the appropriate operators. Simple script, I have here is driving me crazy as it's a super simple, if else statement that should on "mike" being entered run and doesn't work. It outputs the else statement instead. Please help

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
#use warnings;
#use diagnostics;

print("What is your name please?");
$userName = <STDIN>;


if($userName eq "mike"){
    print("correct answer");
}
else{
    print("Wrong answer");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? What's $userName's value?

Comment: $userName value would be whatever is entered by the user, as a scalar variable using <STDIN>.

Comment: Right. But it includes the newline character that the user also entered. Your comparison doesn't take that into account.

Comment: davorg was asking if you ever tried to print the value of `$userName` to see what was really in there.

Comment: I had yes. I did that initially and as STDIN by my understanding used it as a scalar varible, it just printed "mike". All thanks very much again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read your question I thought you were about to have a problem with strings versus numeric values in an equals. Consider the following case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print("What is the meaning of life, the universe and everything? ");
chomp(my $response = <STDIN>);

if ( $response == 42) {
#if ( 42 ~~ $response ) {
    print "correct answer\n";
} else {
    print "Wrong answer\n" ;
}
```

Try the two different `if` statements. Answer something nice like `family` and see what happens. The `~~` is the smart match operator which has helped some of this problem in Perl. Read more about it [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html) (under "smart matching in detail"). Note also the inline use of the `chomp` operator.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding a call to chomp after you get your value from STDIN:

```
$userName = <STDIN>;
chomp($userName);
```

Since the value read in from STDIN will have a newline character on the end. The chomp() built-in will remove a newline from the end of a string.

Comment: *I* can imagine the reason. But these "try <read-made piece of code>" answers are not particular helpful. If you don't understand why, even the correct solution is still cargo cult.

Comment: I just put that down whilst I was editing in a more full description. Bad habit, sorry (probably because of the number of times someone writes something short while I'm writing my long answer.)

Comment: Thanks Fd!. Of course - STDIN appends the end with the \n character, doesn't it?. Many thanks, you're infact correct. I'll have to remember that and am kicking myself as I learnt that at the same time and simply forgot all about it!.

Comment: I remembered as soon as you said as STDIN is a list variable!. Thanks again.